# oledb not registered on your local machine

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I am using OLEDB to connect `.mdb/.accdb` file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using System.data.OLEDB;

class  dbconne
{
.....
.........
.......
.
.
.
.


OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\db1.mdb");

OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from emp_test", aConnection);

aConnection.Open();
....
....
.
.
.
}
```

When I compile this code I don't get any compile errors. But it gives me a runtime error:

```
"Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" provider is not registered on the local machine
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

See if you have [Microsoft Data Access Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937730.aspx) installed.

Jet Oledb provider is part of the above components & should be present for you to connect to the database using the appropriate provider.

On a side note, this should be a part of the operating system (I guess).
Is this your development machine, with .net framework installed?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Jet OLEDB 4.0 is part of Microsoft Access or the Microsoft Access Runtime.  You could [try installing Jet Service Pack 8](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2deddec4-350e-4cd0-a12a-d7f70a153156&displaylang=en), but if that doesn't work, you will need Access or the Access Runtime.  Jet 4.0 is supposed to come with Windows XP.

Starting with Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) version 2.6, MDAC no longer contains the Jet components, so installing MDAC won't work.

Comment: hmmm. I didnt know that. But I think, it is installed as part of .net framework. right?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  It is a deprecated COM technology.